# Python trouble debugging i/0, how do I get the correct format?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, io, fwrite

I am attempting to make a dictionary into a formatted string and then write it to a file, however my entire formatting seems to be incorrect. I'm not sure how to debug since all my tester cases are given different files. I was able to use the interactive mode in python to find out what my function is actually writing to the file, and man is it so wrong! Can you help me correctly format?

Given a sorted dictionary, I created it into a string. I need the function to return it like so:

> Dictionary is : {'orange':[1,3],'apple':[2]}

```
"apple:\t2\norange:\t1,\t3\n"
```

> format is: Every   key-value   pair    of  the dictionary
>   should  be  output  as: a   string  that    starts  with    key,    followed    by  ":",    a   tab,    then    the integers    from    the 
>   value   list.       Every   integer should  be  followed    by  a   "," and a   tab except  for the very    last    one,    which   should  be  followed    by  a   newline

Here is my function that I thought would work:

```
def format_item(key,value):
    return key+ ":\t"+",\t".join(str(x) for x in value) 

def format_dict(d):
    return sorted(format_item(key,value) for key, value in d.items())

def store(d,filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f: 
        f.write("\n".join(format_dict(d)))
        f.close()
    return None
```

I now have too many tabs on the last line. How do I edit the last line only out of the for loop?

ex input:

d   =   {'orange':[1,3],'apple':[2]}

my function gives: ['apple:\t2', 'orange:\t1,\t3']

but should give:    "apple:\t2\norange:\t1,\t3\n"

Comment: Did you mean `format(dict(d))` or `format_dict(d)`?

Comment: format_dict(d), I'll fix.

Comment: Do you get a different result running that?

Comment: It now passes one of my test cases, but fails others. The format is still incorrect.

Comment: It appears that there are now too many tabs on the second value for the second key. (orange). It's getting hung up here:and a tab except for the very last one, which should be followed by a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the newline character to the end of the return statement in format_item seems to yield the correct output.

```
return key+ ":\t"+",\t".join(str(x) for x in value) + '\n'

In [10]: format_dict(d)
Out[10]: ['apple:\t2\n', 'orange:\t1,\t3\n']
```